# Show dialog to rotate iOS app upside down

Tags: ios, dialog, orientation, portrait

I am developing an app which has to be upside down.
I would like to show a dialog to the user, which he can accept (which shall result in a auto rotation) or decline.

How to display such a dialog using objective-c?
I need to check the portrait modes both in the info.plist as well as programatically in the supportedInterfaceOrientations. Right?

Thank you very much in advance for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UIAlertController for this.

```
UIAlertController * alert=[UIAlertController 

alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message"preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

   UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"Yes, please"
                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                        {
                            **//What we write here????????**


                      NSLog(@"you pressed Yes, please button");
                     // call method whatever u need
                        }];
   UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                            actionWithTitle:@"No, thanks"
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                           {
                               **//What we write here????????**


                      NSLog(@"you pressed No, thanks button");
                       // call method whatever u need

                           }];

   [alert addAction:yesButton];
   [alert addAction:noButton];

   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];`
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Sure I will. Unfortunately I am stuck at the rotation see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305964/programmatically-rotate-ios-app-upside-down-using-objective-c)