# Programmatically rotate iOS app upside down using objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation, portrait

I want to rotate my app upside down portrait using the following code in the ViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{    //return NO;
  // Return YES for supported orientations
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}


- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask) supportedInterfaceOrientations

{
  return [super supportedInterfaceOrientations] | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

In the AppDelegate:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window

{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

When the user presses a button

```
NSNumber * value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown];
  [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

The app does somehow not rotate and I have no idea why.
Somebody can give a hint?
Thank you
I added the orientations in the info.plist and set the checkboxes in the general settings in deployment info section.

Comment: Does your application is having Navigation Controller?

Comment: Yes, it has. Why?.

Answer (score 2):

Do I understand you correctly, that you want to programatically want to rotate the user interface, independend from the physical orientation of the device?

This is not how it works: The delegate methods (shouldAutorotate... etc.) are called by iOS when a (physical) rotation of the device is detected, e.g. the user turns it upside down. In the delegate methods you then get the chance to adopt the views to the new orientation, if you need to do so.

In the simulator, you can simulate device rotation by Alt+Left / Alt+Right keys.

Comment: Hi, no, actually I want the user to rotate the device itself and the app should rotate too - otherwise everything will be upside down, right?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rotate the orientation programatically it depends on sensors of the device. However you can rotate the layer of the view.

```
self.view.layer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

Comment: It is very strange, because the orientation change is working in an app, where I only have a single view - I dont know if the problem is related to the fact of having multiple view controllers